# Subselect with multiple results

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to do return results from one table based on multiple results on another. Here's the setup:

```
Table A: "accounts"

id | fname | other_id

1  | test  | 500
2  | test2 | 505
3  | test3 | 500
4  | test4 | 540
5  | test5 | 500

Table B: "transactions"

id | account_id | 

1  | 1          
2  | 4
3  | 2
4  | 1
5  | 3
6  | 2
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is, return all id's from transactions where account_id = the id in table A WHERE other_id = a certain value.

To do write it out manually it would look like this:

So for example if other_id = 500.

1) get records from accounts where other_id = 500 (will be multiple results, in this case, 1, 3 and 5)

2) get records from transactions where account_id = 1 OR account_id = 3 OR account_id = 5

I've tried a few different subselects but can't seem to come up with what I'm looking for.

I of course could just break this up into a loop using PHP but I'd rather use a single query for efficiency.

Comment: I think adding a table with your expected result would have been easier than explaining it in words :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No subselect required, just a simple join.

```
select * from accounts a, transactions t where t.account_id=a.id and other_id=500
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select t.id 
from accounts as a 
inner join transactions as t on a.id = t.account_id
where a.other_id=500
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you right, you want this.

```
SELECT b.id
FROM accounts AS a
LEFT JOIN transactions AS b ON b.account_id = a.id
WHERE other_id = 500
```